# build error - task in 'ns3-core' failed with exit status 1

Tags: ns-3

I am trying to install ns3.33 in ubuntu 20. But I get below build fail error. I tried building with waf, build.py but no luck!

```
from ../src/core/helper/csv-reader.cc:25:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h:3467:5: note: ‘std::max’ declared here
 3467 |     max(initializer_list<_Tp> __l, _Compare __comp)
      |     ^~~

Waf: Leaving directory `/home/kokila/workspace/ns-3-allinone/ns-3.33/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'ns3-core' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)
```

can someone help resolving the issue.